# I symbolize both life and death

Tags: riddle

> I'm red, but I can also be blue 
>  When in a lizard, I might be green
>
> I'm thicker than water, 
>   and I have a slightly higher density.
>
> I  have to do something with a monkey, 
>  but the connection might be negative
>
> I symbolize both life and death

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Blood?

I'm red, but I can also be blue

> humans have red blood, but nobles were sometimes referred to as having blue blood because they never went outside

When in a lizard, I might be green

> [some lizards have green blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasinohaema)

I'm thicker than water, 
and I have a slightly higher density.

> "Blood is thicker than water"

I have to do something with a monkey, 
but the connection might be negative

> [Rhesus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rh_blood_group_system) *(Thanks, @RadoslavHristov!)*

I symbolize both life and death

> You need blood to live, but bloody is often negative and connected with death

Comment: The monkey link is the rhesus factor.
Also insects have no blood so I guess we have a reference to royal, i.e. "blue" blood.

Comment: This was the intended answer. Indeed, blue is a reference to royal. Also, Cephalopods (inkfish) in fact have blue blood.

Comment: If it's not obvious, the "might be negative" part refers to the Rh factor in the blood type, which can be positive or negative like o-positive or ab-negative, for example.